# Where is an Arrow function execution context?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I was reading a [`Execution Context in JavaScript`](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) article, and I undoubtedly understand what is execution context in `JavaScript`.

```
function Foo() {
    // Execution context of Foo function is here, between curly braces
}
```

Also I read about [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and its properties, But a question arose for me:

**Where is an Arrow function execution context?**

```
const ArrowFoo = () => {
    // Where is ArrowFoo function execution context?
    // Is here? or the upper block scope?
    // Or global scope?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The execution context of an arrow function is a function execution context like for all other functions.

Similar too `foo`, the body of the arrow function (between the curly braces) contains the code that executes in this execution context.